# Build a simple link previewer / linter

Tags: php, ajax

I want to be able to grab the Title of a web page from a given URL, much like how Facebook and recently Google plus have a link previewer, but more simplified.

Any hints / tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better to do it with jQuery

//get_new_title.php:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['link'] == "#new_stuff")
{
    echo "My site name - New STUFF!!!";
}

if ($_GET['link'] == "#other stuff")
{
    echo "My site name - Some other stuff";
}
```

//javascript

```
$(function(){
    $("a").bind('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'get_new_title.php?link='+$(this).attr('href'),
                success: function(title){
                    document.title = title;
                }
        });

        //do more stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: But how does this get a link's title? I want to preview the link's title, not the document I'm looking at - a link to another site.

Comment: link's title? So for example you want to grab title from `<a href="#somehash" title="Awesome message">Awesome!</a>` ?

Comment: You know when you post a link on Facebook and it goes off and grabs the Title and some images from that page. I want to build a simple version of that.

Comment: thanks for your help, I found a nice plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jLinkPreview

Comment: YAAAWN, you meant HOVERCARD! Aaaah :)

Comment: well, no not hovercard, but the functionality (using jquery / ajax to get and display title).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing on php, this should do your job

```
function getdoctitle($link) {
$lines = @file($link);
$str=implode(”\n”,$lines);
$str=preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $str, $matches );
if (strpos(” $str”,”<title>”) and strpos(” $str”,”</title>”)) {
$a1=explode(”<title>”,$str);
$str2=$a1[1];
$a2=explode(”</title>”,$str2);
$str3=$a2[0];
return $str3;
} else {
return “”;
}
}
```